# Reading TextBox List in C#

Tags: c#

I have been making this program for about 1 hour now. And I've run into a small problem... I can't find an answer anywhere nor have no clue and how to do it. I basically want to read a textbox of accounts listed like this USERNAME:PASSWORD now how would I separate the : from each other and use them as strings or even use the data separate thanks,

Comment: We can't help you with the code that we can't see.

Comment: Split method https://www.dotnetperls.com/split

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do this, on two way :

First:

```
        string A = "Username:Password";

        string Username = A.Substring(0, A.IndexOf(':'));
        A = A.Substring(A.IndexOf(':') + 1);
        string Password = A;
```

Second:

```
        string A = "Username:Password";
        string[] Items = A.Split(':');
        string Username2 = Items[0];
        string Password2 = Items[1];
```

Comment: Thanks! the second one works great :P but how would i select another line so say if i had USERNAME:PWD and i had another USERNAME:PWD underneath it

Comment: This code : `string[] Lines = A.Split(new string[] { "\r\n" },StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);` will returns all lines. you can use `for` iteration and do above code to split username and password from each line.

Answer (score 0):

You can't ask questions in a way like this. You are not welcome then. Try this:

```
string fullCredentials = YourTextBox.Text;
string username = fullCredentials.Substring(0, fullCredentials.IndexOf(':'));
string password = fullCredentials.Substring(fullCredentials.IndexOf(':') + 1);
```

This is just for a single TextBox.

Comment: Thanks but how would i select another line so say if i had USERNAME:PWD and i had another USERNAME:PWD underneath it

Comment: What do you want to do with them? Do you need all usernames at one place and all passwords at one place too? Or something else? @MrCoInSanity

Comment: so once they have split the usernames and passwords and i want to move on the next line and do the same

Comment: I understand that (that you want to split them all). Look at my question again... I want to know what do you want in order to write some code here. @MrCoInSanity

Comment: I want them to login to a smtp client

Comment: I know that you want to log in. That is logical. My question WAS... Do you want me to store them in a dictionary, list to use it programatically. After looping, use a Dictionary collection. Good luck. @MrCoInSanity

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is the use of `Regex` for more complex operations

```
string text = "USERNAME:PASSWORD";
string[] operands = Regex.Split(text, @"\:+");

foreach (string operand in operands)
{
    Console.WriteLine(operand);
}
```

Comment: Thanks but how would i select another line so say if i had USERNAME:PWD and i had another USERNAME:PWD underneath it